# How to see the PATH inside a shell without opening a shell

Tags: nix, nixos

Use the command flag looked like a solution but it doesn't work

Inside the following shell:

```
nix shell github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello
```

the path contain a directory with an executable hello

I've tried this:

```
nix shell github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello --command echo $PATH
```

I can't see the hello executable

My eyes are not the problem.

```
diff <( echo $PATH ) <( nix shell github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello --command echo $PATH)
```

It see no difference. It means that the printed path doesn't not contains hello.

Why?

Comment: In `nix shell ... --command echo $PATH`, the `$PATH` is expanded by the shell you typed the command into before that shell ever got a chance to start `nix`. Compare to `--command env`

Comment: BTW, as a general rule not specific to your problem at hand, you should always `echo "$PATH"`, not `echo $PATH`. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: (If you come from the Windows world, you might be accustomed to the program that's being started deciding how to interpret its command-line arguments. That's not the case on UNIX: Programs are not passed a single command-line string, but rather an "argument vector" -- an array of individual arguments already parsed out from the original string with shell expansions already performed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printed path does not contain `hello` because if your starting PATH was `/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin`, then you just ran:

```bash
nix shell 'github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello' --command \
  echo /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin
```

That is to say, you passed your *original* path as an argument to the `nix shell` command, instead of passing it a reference to a variable for it to expand later.

---

The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is:

```bash
nix shell 'github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello' --command \
  sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'
```

The single quotes prevent your shell from expanding `$PATH` before a copy of `sh` invoked by nix is started.

---

Of course, if you *really* don't want to start any kind of child shell, then you can run a non-shell tool to print environment variables:

```bash
nix shell 'github:nixos/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable#hello' --command \
  env | grep '^PATH='
```